# Magento 2 : Upload product image programatically

Tags: magento-2.1, product, product-images

I am new to Magento and i want upload upload product programmatically along with product image, i am using this code to implement, please check

```
try{
$_product->setName($product["name"]);
$_product->setTypeId('simple');
$_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
$_product->setSku($product["sku"]); // this must be unique everytime and get the exception in frontend
$_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
$_product->setVisibility(4);
$_product->setDescription($product["description"]);
$_product->setPrice($product["price"]);


//$imagePath = $product['imgpath'];

$_product->setMediaGallery(array('images'=>array (),'values'=>array ())); 
$_product->addImageToMediaGallery('https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg', array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'),false);
// $_product->setImage('https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg');

// $_product->setSmallImage('/testimg/test.jpg');

// $_product->setThumbnail('/testimg/test.jpg');
$_product->setStockData(array(
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
        'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
        'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
        'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
        'is_in_stock' => $product['stockstatus'], //Stock Availability
        'qty' =>  $product['quantity']
        )
    );
$_product->save();
}                 
catch(\Exception $e) { 
 echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

i provided the static path for the image and its opening in the browser, but getting error `The image does not exist.` while uploading product.
please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

The 1st parameter of `addImageToMediaGallery` is the **local** path of the image, NOT remote path. Of course we can have some tweaks. Just download the images to a temporary folder, then add them into the product gallery.

```
/** @var string $tmpDir */
$tmpDir = $this->directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'tmp';
/** create folder if it is not exists */
$this->file->checkAndCreateFolder($tmpDir);
/** @var string $newFileName */
$newFileName = $tmpDir . baseName($imageUrl);
/** read file from URL and copy it to the new destination */
$result = $this->file->read($imageUrl, $newFileName);
if ($result) {
    /** add saved file to the $product gallery */
    $_product->addImageToMediaGallery($newFileName, $imageType, true, $visible);
}
```

Subsitute `$imageUrl` into your image remote URL. You should inject `\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList` in order to use `$this->directoryList` and get constant `DirectoryList::MEDIA`. Also, you need to inject `\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File` to use `$this->file`.

- Ref: https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/import-product-image-from-url/

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes)

Comment: got this errorr

Comment: what if you provide me a way to upload the file from local not from the remote URL , i just want to upload image thats all, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096582/allowed-memory-size-of-x-bytes-exhausted

Comment: how can get $ImageUrl when choose image i try :
        $imageUrl=$_FILES['imageUploader']['name'];
But not read the file